# The ODP.NET is the native oracle provider for .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

I just want to make it sure that this `ODP.NET` is the native provider for oracle design for .net and since when exit's? because some of my partners say that it's pretty new and want to know when was the first release. This all discussion came because they chooses not used entity framework because oracle was not release a native provider for .net in the 2008 and want to check if it's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally the Net Framework 1.1 provided a native Oracle ADO.NET provider in the namespace `System.Data.OracleClient`, but then Microsoft declared it obsolete and stated that these types are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework. (But are still here in Net 4.0). In the meantime Oracle build ODP.NET and now this could be considered the official Oracle Net Provider.

You can download it for free [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)
It comes in 32bit and 64bit versions and, as stated by Oracle, it includes Entity Framework, LINQ, WCF Data Services, and implicit REF CURSOR parameter binding support.

At this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html) you could read numerous FAQ on this provider